# Inherit docstrings in Python class inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, docstring

I'm trying to do some class inheritance in Python. I'd like each class and inherited class to have good docstrings. So I think for the inherited class, I'd like it to:

- inherit the base class docstring
- maybe append relevant extra documentation to the docstring

Is there any (possibly elegant or pythonic) way of doing this sort of docstring manipulation in a class inheritance situation? How about for multiple inheritance?

Comment: I can't answer because the question was unfortunately closed, but as of Python 3.5, [`inspect.getdoc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getdoc) will search the inheritance tree until it finds a docstring.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38414303/974555).

Answer (score 55):

You're not the only one! There was a discussion on `comp.lang.python` about this a while ago, and a recipe was created. Check it out **[here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576862/)**.

```
"""
doc_inherit decorator

Usage:

class Foo(object):
    def foo(self):
        "Frobber"
        pass

class Bar(Foo):
    @doc_inherit
    def foo(self):
        pass 

Now, Bar.foo.__doc__ == Bar().foo.__doc__ == Foo.foo.__doc__ == "Frobber"
"""

from functools import wraps

class DocInherit(object):
    """
    Docstring inheriting method descriptor

    The class itself is also used as a decorator
    """

    def __init__(self, mthd):
        self.mthd = mthd
        self.name = mthd.__name__

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj:
            return self.get_with_inst(obj, cls)
        else:
            return self.get_no_inst(cls)

    def get_with_inst(self, obj, cls):

        overridden = getattr(super(cls, obj), self.name, None)

        @wraps(self.mthd, assigned=('__name__','__module__'))
        def f(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.mthd(obj, *args, **kwargs)

        return self.use_parent_doc(f, overridden)

    def get_no_inst(self, cls):

        for parent in cls.__mro__[1:]:
            overridden = getattr(parent, self.name, None)
            if overridden: break

        @wraps(self.mthd, assigned=('__name__','__module__'))
        def f(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.mthd(*args, **kwargs)

        return self.use_parent_doc(f, overridden)

    def use_parent_doc(self, func, source):
        if source is None:
            raise NameError, ("Can't find '%s' in parents"%self.name)
        func.__doc__ = source.__doc__
        return func

doc_inherit = DocInherit
```

Comment: That's neat for a method to inherit the parent class' method's docstring. That would be useful in many cases I think. I was thinking more about the docstring for the whole class, where I'd like to inherit and append.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. In that case, most of the doc-generation already do that for you.

Answer (score 54):

You can concatenate the docstrings easily:

```
class Foo(object):
    """
    Foo Class.
    This class foos around.
    """
    pass

class Bar(Foo):
    """
    Bar class, children of Foo
    Use this when you want to Bar around.
    parent:
    """ 
    __doc__ += Foo.__doc__
    pass
```

However, that is useless. Most documentation generation tool ([Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) and [Epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/) included) will already pull parent docstring, including for methods. So you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Indeed, most documentation tools do that. But the built-in help() function doesn't.

Comment: @MarioVilas: perhaps that's a bug that should be reported?

Comment: Sphinx doesn't seem to be doing that for me, perhaps because my parent is "private" aka name starts with an underscore.

Answer (score 9):

Starting with Python 3.5, docstrings are now inherited if a subclass doesn't have any documentation.

You can use [inspect.getdoc()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getdoc) accordingly:

```
import inspect

class A:
  """Hello"""

class B(A):
  pass

class C(B):
  __doc__ = inspect.getdoc(B) + " World"
```

Do note that the builtin help function pulls recursively only for overridden functions but not for class docstring for some odd reason:

```
class A:
  """Hello"""
  def test():
    """Testdoc"""

class B(A):
  def test():
    pass

>>> help(B.test)
... Testdoc ...
>>> help(B)
...  # No "Hello".
```

Answer (score 7):

Not particularly elegant, but simple and direct:

```
class X(object):
  """This class has a method foo()."""
  def foo(): pass

class Y(X):
  __doc__ = X.__doc__ + ' Also bar().'
  def bar(): pass
```

Now:

```
>>> print Y.__doc__
This class has a method foo(). Also bar().
```

Comment: If you want to do this for the `Init docstring` as well, is there a way to do it in the definition of `Y`? The only way I have been able to do it is using `__init__.__doc__ = X.__init__.__doc__ + " Also another param"` following the `__init__` definition in `Y` but this seems to mess with the formatting, causing extra added spaces.

Answer (score 7):

A mixed stile that can preserve both the inherited docstring syntax and the preferred ordering can be:

```
class X(object):
  """This class has a method foo()."""
  def foo(): pass

class Y(X):
  """ Also bar()."""
  __doc__ = X.__doc__ + __doc__
  def bar(): pass
```

With the same output as Alex's one:

```
>>> print Y.__doc__
This class has a method foo(). Also bar().
```

**Thin ice:** playing with docstring can make your module unusable with `python -OO`, expect some:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Answer (score 7):

I wrote [custom_inherit](https://github.com/meowklaski/custom_inherit) to provide some simple, light weight tools for handling docstring inheritance.

It also comes with some nice default styles for merging different types of docstrings (e.g. Numpy, Google, and reST formatted docstrings). You can also provide your own style very easily.

Overlapping docstring sections will defer to the child's section, otherwise they are merged together with nice formatting.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very old thread. But If anyone is looking for a simple way, you can do this with `__init_subclass__` which is called whenever you inherit that class.

```py
def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
    super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
    parent_method_docstr = {}
    for i, v in ParentClass.__dict__.items():
        if v and callable(v) and v.__doc__ is not None:
            parent_method_docstr[i] = v.__doc__

    for i, v in cls.__dict__.items():
        if v and callable(v) and v.__doc__ is None and i in parent_method_docstr:
            v.__doc__ = parent_method_docstr[i]
```

Comment: What is `ParentClass`? I don't think that's part of a default name space. I believe you need to access `cls.__bases__[-1]` (or a different index, maybe). (Otherwise, very helpful. Thanks.)