# Docstring inheritance for properties using sphinx's autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a class like this:

```
class MyBase(object):
   x = 3
   """Documentation for property x"""
```

and another class that inherits it:

```
class MyObj(MyBase):
   x = 0
```

When I use sphinx's autodoc to generate documentation, `MyObj.x` is not documented. Is there any way to inherit the docstring from `MyBase.x`? I found [DocInherit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025562/inherit-docstrings-in-python-class-inheritance) but since this uses a decorator, it only works for class methods. Any way to do this with properties?

Comment: Not to second guess you too much, but... your doc has the inheritance tree.  Why wouldn't the user of `MyObj` just click the link to go to the parent object and then look at the parent object's documentation there?

Comment: That's a possibility, but I think it's much nicer to have all of a class's methods and attributes (including inherited ones) on a single page instead of having to look through its type hierarchy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a workaround using the property function:

```
class MyBase(object):
   _x = 3
   x = property( lambda s: s._x, doc="Documentation for property x")

class MyObj(MyBase):
   _x = 0
```

This is nice in that given an instance variable:

```
>>> m = MyObj()
>>> m.x
0
```

one can call `help(m)` and get proper documentation of property `x` and sphinx also picks this up correctly.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, docstrings for attributes are not part of Python. When I try it, `MyBase.x.__doc__` does not get set to the string beneath it. Docstrings only work on classes, functions and methods. If Sphinx picks up the string underneath `x = 3` as a docstring, it's probably doing its own processing of the source code to get that.

Comment: This led me to think I should be using ``property()`` with the ``doc`` parameter. See my answer. It's kind of ugly, but I think it's probably the best way to do it, unless you have any better suggestions.

Comment: @jterrace: I'm certainly not keen on turning x into a property with a getter just to add a docstring. I don't think there's another way to do it, but I generally leave attributes without a docstring, or describe the important ones in the class' docstring.

Comment: @Thomas-K: I agree, but the alternative is to duplicate the docstring which makes maintaining the documentation quite annoying.

Answer (score 3):

If you only care for building Documentation via Sphinx. you can use:
":inherited-members:"

```
.. autoclass:: Noodle
   :members:
   :inherited-members:
```

This will also add the doc strings of inherited members in Sphinx Documentation.

http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas already stated, attributes do not have docstrings in Python. Sphinx however provides it's own processing allowing for attributes to be documented.

```
class Test(object):
    #: This is an attibute docstring.
    test_attr = 'test'

    @property
    def test_prop(self):
        """This is a property docstring."""
```

This results in:

```
class Test
    Bases: object

    test_attr = 'test'
        This is an attibute docstring.

    test_prop
        This is a property docstring.
```