# Why isn't Sphinx showing inherited members?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a base class `Base` and a derived class `Derived`. Using Sphinx, I want the class attributes of `Base` to appear in the documentation of `Derived`; I thought `:inherited-members:` would do the trick, but I'm having no luck so far.

Note that unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344289/how-can-i-show-inherited-members-of-a-class-in-my-sphinx-documentation), the members I need to document do not appear hard-coded in the class, only in the class docstring.

Minimal working example: under `tmp/`, I have the file `a.py`:

```
class Base:
    """
    :param x: X
    :type x: int
    """
    x = 1


class Derived(Base):
    """
    :param y: Y
    :type y: int
    """
    y = 2
```

the file `index.rst`:

```
Tmp
===

.. autoclass:: tmp.a.Base
    :members:

.. autoclass:: tmp.a.Derived
    :show-inheritance:
    :inherited-members:
    :members:
```

and `conf.py`, which only contains `extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']`. If I run the command

```
python -m sphinx.cmd.build . ./tmphtml/
```

then the output `tmphtml/index.html` shows this:

[image]

How can I get `x` to appear under the **Parameters** part of **Derived**? My current version of Sphinx is 3.3.1.

Comment: The example looks "too minimal". There are no methods, no class attributes and no instance attributes. What does it mean to have `:param:` in the class docstring?

Comment: I think you need to provide a more realistic example with classes that have actual members.

Comment: @mzjn edited (added class attributes). Same result

Comment: It still looks strange. x and y are not parameters; they are class attributes/variables.

Comment: @mzjn edited the question to reflect this. This is the use case I have, if this isn't possible and not on the roadmap I'd be happy to accept such an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a bug in Sphinx, but there's also a mistake in your example.

Your mistake is that you didn't document the `x` or `y` class attributes correctly.  The `:param:` role is meant for describing function arguments, so Sphinx doesn't associate the `x` and `y` parameters with the class attributes of the same names.  And then since Sphinx considers the class attributes undocumented, it doesn't include them in the documentation.  Here is how the attributes should be documented:

```py
class Base:
    x = 1
    """Spam"""

class Derived(Base):
    y = 2
    """Eggs"""
```

The (possible) bug is that even when you do this, Sphinx *still* considers the attributes undocumented.  I think this is probably a consequence of attributes not having true docstrings, which forces Sphinx to do some tricks behind the scenes to make it seems like they do, but I'm not really sure.  In any case, you can work around this behavior by including `:undoc-members:` in the `.. autoclass::` directive.  This will of course include every undocumented method/attribute in the documentation, but I couldn't figure out a way around this.

An alternative worth mentioning is a plugin I wrote called [`autoclasstoc`](https://autoclasstoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).  This is basically an easy way to have the documentation for `Derived` include links to the documentation for both `x` and `y`.  The `y` documentation would actually be on the same page, since it's part of the `Derived` class, while the `x` documentation would be on the `Base` page.  There'd also be nicely organized links for every method (including inherited ones).  This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I think it gets at the same idea.