# What is the reason that child class does not inherit `__doc__` property/method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, docstring

I am a bit confused about the difference in behavior between `__doc__` and other methods:

```py
# python 3.10.13
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, doc):
        self._doc = doc

    def __doc__(self):
        return self._doc
    
    def __other__(self):
        return self._doc


class Child(Parent):
    pass


>>> print(Parent("test").__doc__())
test

>>> print(Child("test").__doc__)
None # TypeError if call __doc__() since it is not defined
>>> print(Child("test").__other__())
test
```

But it does not work as property either:

```py
# python 3.10.13
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, doc):
        self._doc = doc

    @property
    def __doc__(self):
        return self._doc

    @property
    def __other__(self):
        return self._doc

class Child(Parent):
    pass


>>> print(Parent("test").__doc__)
test

>>> print(Child("test").__doc__)
None
>>> print(Child("test").__other__)
test
```

This is mentioned and somewhat discussed here @[22750354](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937500/inherit-a-parent-class-docstring-as-doc-attribute), but I need help finding out why the Child class does not inherit the method/property of `__doc__`. And are there other methods like `__doc__` in terms of inheritance? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a first approximation<sup>1</sup>, when you write

```
obj.a
```

Python attempts to lookup `a` by

1. checking whether `obj` has an attributed named `a`, then
2. checking whether `obj`'s class (`obj.__class__`) has an attribute `a`, then
3. recursively checking each parent class (`obj.__class__.__mro__`) for an attribute `a`.

If at any point, an attribute named `a` is found, that then that object gets returned as the result. This is what is inheritance means in Python. Child classes don't copy their parents, they just *delegate* attribute lookups to them.

Now, whenever you define a class as

```
class Child(Parent):
    ...
```

that class object *always* gets assigned a `__doc__` attribute: the docstring if one was provided, or `None` otherwise.

```
>>> Child.__doc__ is None
True
```

Because of this, any lookups for the attribute `__doc__` will only ever propagate up to the class level before a matching object is found. Attribute lookup will never reach the stage of checking the parent classes.

<sub><sup>1</sup>The complete attribute lookup process is much more complicated. See [3.3.2. Customizing attribute access](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) from the Python Data Model docs for the bigger picture.</sub>

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if I check `object.__dict__` for example, all the "__" methods are bound method/slot wrappers, only `__doc__` is assigned a value which is the docstring. So I can expect the behavior is only limited to `__doc__`?

Comment: @Peter Actually, `__doc__` isn't any different than those other attributes. They're all just attributes that reference some objects (they all are assigned a value). The only things that makes `__doc__` seem different are 1) it tends to reference a `str` object, instead of something more exotic like a descriptor, and 2) it's among the special attributes that are always assigned on new class objects (like `__class__`, `__module__`, `__mro__`, ...)