# Avoid docstrings from parent, in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring

I use Sphinx for autodocs, but I find it annoying how it by default appends the parent class docstring to my docstring.

The result is that for each and every documented test class inheriting from `unittest.TestCase`, I get the docstring *"Create an instance of the class that will use the named test method when executed. Raises a ValueError if the instance does not have a method with the specified name."* appended. So these two sentences litter my test documentation, over and over again.

How can I stop Sphinx from pulling the docstring from the parent?

Comment: I guess pure Python trickery inspired by answers found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025562/inherit-docstrings-in-python-class-inheritance?lq=1 is out of the question, since Sphinx itself seems to pull the docstring from the parent.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [setting](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_inherit_docstrings):

> #### autodoc_inherit_docstrings
>
> This value controls the docstrings inheritance. If set to `True` the docstring for classes or methods, if not explicitly set, is inherited form (sic) parents.
>
> The default is `True`.
>
> *New in version 1.7.*

Although use with care - this setting appears to break a directive I'm calling in docstrings.