# Telling sphinx not to include base class

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a module named wrapper_iperf which basically wraps some calls to iperf3. The module contains a class named "ThreadWithReturnValue(Thread)" which is obviously derived from Thread.

This class contains the overriden methods `run` and `join`.

```
class ThreadWithReturnValue(Thread):

    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}):
        pass

    def run(self):
        pass

    def join(self, *args):
        pass
```

Now I am trying to document the behaviour of the remaining module. To do that, I use sphinx and the following rst file:

```
.. automodule:: wrapper_iperf
    :members:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:
```

Now, when I build the documentation I will ALWAYS get the description for the base class "Thread" and the methods `run` and `join`.

If I use `:inherited-members: ThreadWithReturnValue` I will get even more documentation for all members from the Thread base class.

If I document those member functions myself in my inherited class, I will get the output from my inherited class.

How do I tell sphinx that I don't want the documentation for this specific class "Thread" repeated in my documentation?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/16518834/407651

Comment: Ohhhhh yes, that was it. Parent class was the keyword. Thanks