# Sphinx: How to include doc strings from super method?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I can't seem to find any way to get sphinx to include doc strings from super methods.  For example:

```
class Base(object):
    def a_method(self, param_a, param_b, **kwargs):
        """ This is an adapter method which must be implemented by each Sub class.

        :param param_a: Param A Available to all adapters.
        :type param_a: str
        :param param_b: Param B Available to all adapters.
        :type param_b: str
        """
        raise NotImplementedError('This method must be implemented in each Sub')


class Sub (Base):
    def a_method(self, param_a, param_b, param_c, **kwargs):
        """ Adapted for interface with this unique API.

        :param param_c: An option unique to this API.
        :type param_c: str
        """
        ... obtain data from API here ...
        return result
    # UPDATE TO ORIGINAL: this will combine the docs
    method_a.__doc__ += Base.method_a.__doc__
    # Now i need to combine params so that Sub supersedes Super and
    # incorporate this into sphinx.
```

I would like the documentation for Sub to include param_a from Base, param_b from Base, and param_c from Sub in the docs for Sub.a_method.  Any way to get the output to look like this?

class **Sub**()
----**a_method**(param_a, param_b, param_c, **kwargs)
--------Super A method docs
--------Sub A method docs
--------**Parameters**:
-----------**Param_a** (str) – Param A.
-----------**Param_b** (str) – Param B.
-----------**Param_c** (str) – Param C.

Comment: You could put an explicit link to it in the subclass implementation docstring.

Comment: yes, that's what i'm doing now and gets the job done.  It would be better to actually have the docs right there.  Instead of a link i'm looking for an import...

Comment: would this work : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2025599/671543 ? (or does it only work for classes?)

Comment: @njk2 Gave it a shot and the docstring for ``Sub.a_method`` is unaffected

Comment: @njk2 Actually it does work!  Not ideal, but it does combine the doc strings.  Still i wonder if this is possible via some existing sphinx directive that i have overlooked,

Comment: It's not a directive, but autodoc's [docstring-preprocessing](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#docstring-preprocessing) feature might be helpful.  It lets you modify the docstring in place as the docs are generated.

Comment: Thanks @morric , this is interesting. Now i just need to find a way to incorporate ``method_a.__doc__ += Base.method_a.__doc__``.  I need one list of params combined where Sub.method_a params supersede Super.method_a params.. Almost there –  arctelix 22 mins ago

Comment: Actually, keeping the combine statement in the class could be a good thing. This way the docs are combined in python doc access as well as sphinx.

Comment: Not sure how relevant this is, but OP, your code shows poor design.  It violates the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), since it is legal to call `base_instance.a_method(x, y)`, but illegal to make the same call on an instance of `Sub`.  That might be why Sphinx doesn't let you supersede params like that.

Comment: @ kevin, Are you referring to addition of param_c to the base method? If so i would agree (bad example code).  However, your quote "illegal to make the same call on an instance of Sub" is a pattern that i see all the time.... As long as the inheritance chain is: shape -> four_sided_shape -> rectangle OR shape -> four_sided_shape -> square AND NOT shape -> four_sided_shape -> triangle.