# Inherit a function (incl. docstring) as a class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, docstring

Imagine, there is a function like this

```
def bar(a: str, b: str):
    """
    Do somehting with a and b.
    """
    print(a, b)
```

Then there is a class, where i would like to adapt this function, but keep the docstring (and also the dynamic autocomplete and help) of the original function.

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self, **kwargs):
        bar(a=kwargs.get("a"), b=kwargs.get("b"))
        print("This was called fro the class method")
```

How do i dynamically link the original function to the class, including docstrings?
And are kwargs the best way to pass the arguments, without repeating them in the definition of the class-method?

So when i type `Foo.foo()` in my IDE or jupyter notebook, i would like to see the docstring of foo().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inherit docstrings in Python class inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025562/inherit-docstrings-in-python-class-inheritance)

Comment: @RvdK i found that already, but as i am not doing a class inheritance, i couldn't get it to work for my case

Comment: See comment by https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025599/47351: have you tried: _ _ doc _ _ += bar.__doc__

Comment: Yes, i have tried, but it also does not work. Or i am putting it in wrong position.